# Can't update foreign key in an entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

These are my models:

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(null)]
    public virtual Image Thumbnail { get; set; }

    public void SetViewModelValues(CreatePostViewModel viewModel)
    {
        Title = viewModel.Title;
    }
}

public class CreatePostViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int? ThumbnailId { get; set; }
}
```

And the action:

```
    public ActionResult CreatePost(CreatePostViewModel postViewModel, int? id)
    {
        Post post;

        if (id != null)
        {
            post = dbWebContent.Posts.Find(id);
            if (post == null)
                return HttpNotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            post = new Post();
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(post);

        post.SetViewModelValues(postViewModel);
        post.Thumbnail = null; // Even setting null doesn't work

        var state = (post.Id == 0) ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
        dbWebContent.Entry(post).State = state;

        if (dbWebContent.SaveChanges() > 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Success = true;
            return View(post);
        }

        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Error!";
        return View(post);
    }
```

The problem is that when I try to update `Thumbnail` property it doesn't make any change in the database. `SaveChanges` method returns 1 (even if Thumbnail is the only modified property). Even when I try to set it to null. Everything works when creating new post. But editing is not working.
What is the problem? Is there any better solution to handle Add/Update operations in one action?

These are not all my properties in `Post` class (no other foreign keys). The second question is: is there any better way for creating an entity from view model? I mean do I need to store all these properties values in two separate objects and then copy it from view model to entity or is there any prettier way to do that?

Comment: What do you do with `ThumbnailId`? Are you sure that `ModelState` is valid?

Comment: Thumbnail is translated in what column type in your database? For your second question, you can use Automapper for that: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Comment: `ModelState` is valid, I'm sure. There is the `Images` table in my database created from `Image` class. `ThumbnailId` is the foreign key of this table so I use it to find the `Image` in that table. But it doesn't work just as simple setting `Thumbnail` to null doesn't.

Comment: what I mean is that it's nowhere actively involved in your (visible) code.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, it seems to be because you're not using `ThumbnailId` from your viewmodel. Here's one way to populate `Thumbnail`:

```
public void SetViewModelValues(CreatePostViewModel viewModel)
{
    Title = viewModel.Title;
    Thumbnail = viewModel.ThumbnailId != null ? db.Images.Find(viewModel.ThumbnailId) : null;
}
```

Also, what do you mean it works when creating a new Post? The Thumbnail is created with a non-null value?

Comment: When adding new post (not editing existing one), thumbnail is properly set (to null or some valid image). What's the difference between setting it in `SetViewModelValues` and in `CreatePost`? I can't see any.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't want why this happened but I deleted all tables in my database and recreated them. Now it's working.